# how to install eiskaltdc++ on fedora 19?

Tags: fedora

So, recently i switched from [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu) to [fedora](/questions/tagged/fedora). I was using eiskaltdc++ for file sharing before.

I have installed linuxdc++ on fedora but that is not working though. I would like to install eiskaltdc++ on fedora.

Comment: You are looking for an equivalent, right?

Answer (score 1):

According to the googlecode project for [eiskaltdc++](https://code.google.com/p/eiskaltdc/) there are rpms available at the RussianFedora [repo](http://mirror.yandex.ru/fedora/russianfedora/russianfedora/free/fedora/releases/18/Everything/x86_64/os/)

Comment: please explain regarding installation

Comment: rpm -U thepackage.rpm

Answer (score 1):

You can install Valknut, which is another wonderful Direct Connect Client.
The benefit of using Valknut is, it is available in the official yum repository so is easy to install.

I personally prefer Valknut over Eisaklt, as it is more stable and available in the official Fedora repository, so more reliable.

To install Eiskalt

```
cd/etc/yum.repos.d
```

Make a new text file russianfedora-free

{
[russianfedora-free]
name=Russian Fedora for Fedora $releasever - Free

## baseurl=http://mirror.yandex.ru/fedora/russianfedora/russianfedora/free/fedora/releases/$releasever/Everything/$basearch/os

mirrorlist=http://mirrors.rfremix.ru/mirrorlist?repo=free-fedora-$releasever&arch=$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-russianfedora-free-fedora
}

> Blockquote

```
sudo -y yum install eiskaltdcpp.x86_64
```

This should install Eiskalt. You can also make repo file for updates.